# windows script to change date and run command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a command which i am using to get audit report on daily basis. I want to schedule it in windows scheduler using the command or script. It can be .bat or .cmd scripting. The command is :

```
<Install_Path>\nbauditreport.exe -sdate "MM/DD/YY 00:00:00" -edate "MM/DD/YY 23:59:59"
```

So in this command everything will be same leaving MM, DD and YY. So how can i replace day, month and year from the command?

The date is one day previous date of current. For example, the command is scheduled to run on 07 July 2017 at 09:00 AM, In that case the command will be:

```
<Install_Path>\nbauditreport.exe -sdate "07/06/17 00:00:00" -edate "07/06/17 23:59:59"
```

How can I create the script for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your mask "MM/DD/YY" meant to have only 2 digits for the year?
Then change in the following batch to only two `yy` but leave the casing as is.

```
@echo off
For /f %%Y in (
  'powershell -NoP -C "(get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString(\"MM\/dd\/yy\")"'
) Do Set Yesterday=%%Y
"X:\Path\to\nbauditreport.exe" -sdate "%Yesterday% 00:00:00" -edate "%Yesterday% 23:59:59"
```

Schedule this batch.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, Can I modify the date in script from 08-15-17 to 08/15/17 as I need format of date MM/DD/YY.

Comment: Sorry the `/` in the date format had to be escaped with a backslash `\/`to have them literal. Changed above.

Comment: Thanks for the script. Issue Solved. :-)