# Creating Jmeter Report

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a scheduled load test which runs daily. Scripts are triggered from CLI (.bat file) and will be creating a html report at the end of the test.

I am saving test report with `testnameDATE`, where currently the date part is updated manually.

I tried to automate the date part to get the system date on run time using '${__time(MMddyyyy)}', but for html part its not working and report is not getting created.

Eg:

```
D:
cd D:\Performance Testing\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin
jmeter -n -t "D:\Performance Testing\batch\DailyRun\Test_DailyRegression.jmx" -l "D:\Performance Testing\batch\DaiyRun\csv\Test${__time(MMddyyyy)}_001.csv"   -e -o "D:\Performance Testing\batch\DaiyRun\html\Test${__time(MMddyyyy)}_001.html"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a file name as a timestamp in a batch job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064557/creating-a-file-name-as-a-timestamp-in-a-batch-job)

Comment: You should use command line syntax, like in linked question, not JMeter syntax

Comment: @Kiril That's a rather old Q&A, today I'd recommend a user settings/locale independent solution using wmic or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683402/6811411).

Comment: You didn't quote a path containing  spaces, that should be `cd /d "D:\Performance Testing\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't know anything about [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), given you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) you will need to use [date](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) command instead like:

```
jmeter -n -t ..\extras\Test.jmx -l Test_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_001.csv
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter create timestamp results]